# How to change volume of randomised audio

Tags: javascript, audio

So essentially the audio played is incredibly loud, how would I go about changing the volume of whichever song plays from the array?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var sound = new Array();
sound[0]= "Attack.mp3"
sound[1]= "KOTD.mp3"
sound[2]= "Revenge.mp3"
sound[3]= "Attack.mp3"
sound[4]= "KOTD.mp3"
sound[5]= "Revenge.mp3"
var randomsound = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
document.write ('<audio id="sound" loop autoplay preload><source src= "' + sound[randomsound] + '" hidden=true type="audio/mpeg" autostart=true loop=true>')
</script>
```

I've tried using the audio.volume function but to no avail, any help?

Comment: Do you mean you want to set the volume or change it at a specific point? I would also recommend you create and append the element to the DOM rather than using `document.write()`

Comment: Set the volume as a static

Comment: Much easier solution: can you go back and change the individual volumes of the mp3s? Or you're stuck with the files you have?